# Unable to connect to wcf server with non-wcf client using basic authenication over TLS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

The issue I'm having with the non-WCF client occurs after the secure connection is established, and the requested URL string is passed to the server. Instead of getting a 401 challenge, I get a 403 forbidden error.  I have a WCF client that works with both the `WsHTTPBinding` and `BasicHTTPBinding`. After testing the WCF client, I can make it fail basic authentication by replacing `CertificateName` with an empty string in the following line of code prior to calling `serviceProxy.CheckIn()`:

```
PermissiveCertificatePolicy.Enact(string.Format("CN={0}", CertificateName));
```

I'm guessing this is either an override forcing the client to accept the server certificate, or it somehow passes it's name to the server for identity validation.

So my question is does a WCF client pass the certificate name to the server during the request? And if so, where in the request string should I place it? And what would it look like?

**web.config** file bindings:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HIBridge_SSLBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="True" establishSecurityContext="True"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HIBridge_BasicBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        </security>
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```